# How can I use share and save functinality in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to give a functionality to a photo sharing web site and the option of sharing and saving links. What would the code look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not positive what you mean, but if you are wanting to let someone share a page, I would recommend going with a service that does the heavy lifting for you. One of these two would work nicely, and I am sure there other services that do a similar thing.

1. [ShareThis](http://sharethis.com/)
2. [AddThis](http://addthis.com/)

I realize these links run fully client side, but this is by far the easiest way to get this functionality. If you are looking for RoR server side code, controllers, etc, you will need to elaborate on your question.

Comment: Hey Doug Neiner ,, You are so quick in answering ,, 
I wanted exactly the same but ,, and ya elaborating my question i would like to know the code of view side and controller side. Please help me ,

Comment: @Arpit Hey man, I am sorry but your question like that is too vague and too open to answer. I would have to code the whole functionality just to show you how it works. You will get great answers here on SO if you try yourself, then post code when you get stuck so we can help with specific problems.

Comment: oh k thank you sir. and what ever you sent in earlier post helped me a lot , i will try to post query if i got struck ,
Thank you.